# How to check if an object exists in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, object, nsmutablearray

Is there a method, like containsObject: for NSMUtableArrays to check if an object exists in there without having to loop through the whole array and check each element? What's the best way to check if an object exists in an NSMutableArray?

Comment: Always check the documentation of the superclass

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency, the containsObject method will still, ultimately, loop through the array until the first instance of `object` appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're mostly using an array to check if an object exists, *and* you're using unique elements, you may want to use an [`NSSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Checking a set for membership is faster than checking an array.

Answer (score 12):

`NSMutableArray` inherits from `NSArray`, so all of the `NSArray` methods work for `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: awakeFromNib: Worth noting: This is true generally. Unless otherwise stated in a method's documentation, all methods of a class will work on any subclass (or instance of a subclass) of that class. You'll take advantage of this most often with methods of the plist classes (with their mutable versions), NSView, NSControl, NSCell, and, of course, NSObject.